# Anchor link isnt working inside nested ui-li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created fiddle on following link

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c6SXD/)

I have created nested `ul-li`. and given `anchor` tag inside li

Dont know why anchor tag isnt working

Any Solutions

Comment: It's because your li is the parent, and the jQuery says something needs to happen when you click on the li. Therefore it closes again instead of going to the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function jsddm_open(event) {
    jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
    if (submenu.length) {
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2p8sn/)

the main problem is `if (submenu) {` because `.find()` returns a jQuery object which will always be truthy so your handler will return false every time preventing the default action of the click

Answer (score 1):

You can use [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) for the links inside your list item to prevent `click` event bubble up:

```
$('#jsddm ul li a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6SXD/1/)**